# Gradle sub-project classes dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I've got several sub-projects in my gradle project:

```
Project
    Common
    Consumer1
    Consumer2
    .....
    ConsumerN
```

My first - and main goal – is to include classes from `Common` project into resulting jar of every `ConsumerN` projects. So I can develop and test shared part (DB logic, some utils) independently in `Common` project and next other projects will get this classes (already tested) and include them into their jars.

Second goal is to make IntelliJ Idea to understand such dependency and work with it correctly.

Would you please suggest the "most conceptual and right way" to do this in gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Assume You have the following project structure:

- root

  - build.gradle
  - common
  - m1
  - m2
  - m3
  - settings.gradle

First of all You need to set a multimodule project - it's done in `settings.gradle` (this is a normal gradle script) and its content is as follows:

```
include 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'common'
```

Per project settings are done in dedicated `build.gradle` files, but the settings You asked can be done globally - in root `build.gradle`. Here's its content:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

subprojects.findAll { it.name != 'common' }.each { 
    configure(it) {
        dependencies {
            project(':common')
        }
    }
}
```

The question is what artifacts are produced from `mN` modules. If these are jar files You need to use [fatjar](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) or [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin. If there are web applications war plugin is what You need.

Some further [reading](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

IntelliJ IDEA should handle these dependencies while importing the project using gradle wrapper.